# Why is this angular keypress event bound to $document firing twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular directive that binds all keypress events on the $document and broadcasts them to rootScope.

The problem is that it fires twice for every single keypress. Why is this happening? I have even removed the rootScope broadcast piece but I am still seeing double events being picked up

```
.directive('keypressEvents', function ($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function () {
            console.log('Linking keypress listener to document.');
            $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
                console.log('keypress detectected on $document. Broadcasting to $rootScope');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, String.fromCharCode(e.which));
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I use this in a view as such:

```
<div class="row topPad60 leftPad70" keypress-events ng-cloak> 
 other stuff...
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I have attempted to unbind the listen but I am still seeing events fired twice even on first pageload(meaning directive should not have loaded again)

Comment: Probably because you never unbind it, and every time that link function is ran another event is bound. It's likely running twice because you have both ng-controller and some other kind of routing, thus loading the controller and view twice.

Comment: I am using ui-router for routing...could this be related? Do i need to do something to "unbind"? or fix my routing?

Comment: directives have a destroy event, though, i'd consider doing this somewhere else rather than a directive to avoid needlessly binding and unbinding events.

Comment: you can pass scope in your link and do a  `scope.$on('$destroy', function() { unbind }` .  OR bind on the compile

Comment: @KevinB where would the best place be to add global kepress listeners? Essentially, in any controller i want to be able to handle keypress events as they occur for the functionality specific to the current view

Comment: the .run might be an ok place to do it, i'm not too familiar with binding such global events with angular though.